# Port legacy C# Rijndael encryption algorithm to nodejs with the crypto module

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rijndael

I am migrating a C# .NET 4.8 Framework code base to the cloud. The new architecture uses nodejs firebase functions. These functions only allow nodejs code.

The following code is used to validate an input text password with a hash stored in a database. The application is migrating to a SSO solution but will allow users to claim data from their old accounts by validating their prior credentials.

The following code is generating a key and initialization vector using [RFC2898](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8.1), which is now called PBKDF2, and providing those to the [Rijndael](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=netframework-4.8.1) object to setup the encryption.

This method combines the password with the salt for some reason, presumably to increase the length of the password. The salt is always 36 characters. It then uses a pepper where the salt would typically go. And finally, the encrypted value is output as a base64 string.

```csharp
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

var password = "password123";
var salt = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var pepper = "yyyyyyyy";

var enc = new UTF8Encoding();
var keyGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password + salt, enc.GetBytes(pepper));

var key = keyGen.GetBytes(32);
var iv = keyGen.GetBytes(16);

var cipher = new RijndaelManaged
{
  Key = key,
  IV = iv
};

Console.WriteLine("Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(key));
Console.WriteLine("IV: " + Convert.ToBase64String(iv));

var plainText = enc.GetBytes(password + salt);
using var encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor();
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
using var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
cs.FlushFinalBlock();

Console.WriteLine("Hash: " + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
```

Using nodejs 18 and the [crypto](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/crypto.html) package, I am able to create equivalent keys and iv's as the C# code above using the following code.

```js
const generatePbkdf2Values = (password, pepper) => {
  const pepperBytes = Buffer.from(pepper, 'utf8');

  const iterations = 1000;
  const length = 32 + 16;
  const digest = 'sha1';
  const keyPlusIv = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(
    password,
    pepperBytes,
    iterations,
    length,
    digest
  );

  return {
    key: keyPlusIv.subarray(0, 32),
    iv: keyPlusIv.subarray(32, length),
  };
};
```

I've read that Rijndael is a [variant of AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with a fixed block size. Therefore, I was hoping to be able to use the crypto's package [createCipheriv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatedecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options) method to encrypt text but I am struggling to do so. I fear the C# settings or defaults are not compatible or I'm not configuring them properly. This is where I would like your advice.

### A few assumptions

1. The IV is a 16 byte/128 bit key which would require the `aes-128-cbc` algorithm. But the 128 algorithm throws a key length error so it must be based on the key which is a 32 byte/256 bit key requiring the `aes-256-cbc` algorithm.
2. The C# Rijndael algorithm uses PKCS7 padding by default and so does `crypto.createCipheriv` via [cipher.setAutoPadding(true)](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#ciphersetautopaddingautopadding)
3. The key and iv from the nodejs method are creating equivalent values as C#

The following is the nodejs that I am using to hash the text. `key`, `iv`, `password`, and `salt` come from the snippets above.

```js
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

const passwordAndSalt = Buffer.from(password + salt, 'utf8');
const encoding = 'hex';
const inputEncoding = encoding;
const outputEncoding = encoding

let result = cipher.update(passwordAndSalt, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
result += cipher.final(outputEncoding);

console.log(result.toString('base64'));
```

This provides a string that has 32 more characters than the C# solution and shares no pattern.

The correct hash with the values above is `DC07eaMXkaeK26KTIt3ldtzTdISTH5j9cmrg3OzFF16MvfKkEi9ihEkI8VDLzNvU`

As a plan B, I tried to use the [rinjndael-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rijndael-js) npm package. Using the same key and iv from above, the following code produces almost the correct hash but not quite.

```js
import Rijndael from 'rijndael-js';

const cipher = new Rijndael(key, 'cbc');
const text = Buffer.from(password + salt, 'utf8');

return Buffer.from(cipher.encrypt(text, 16, iv)).toString('base64')
```

This produces a hash that is the same length and is 68% equivalent. The first 43 characters match and the last 21 do not. It would be my preference to use the built in crypto package to create the same hash. Is it possible? Can you spot my errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The IV has the size of a block, which is always 128 bits for AES. The block size is not the same thing as the key size. I'm assuming that the salt and pepper are not included in the code, if that is the case then the key will be the same for each piece of data that is encrypted, leading to security issues.  You've got it backwards. AES is Rijndael with restrictions on the key and block size. Rijndael is the algorithm, AES is the standardized version of it. The org. author should probably have used `Aes.Create()` instead of `RijndaelManaged`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike the actual salts and peppers are not shown in the code no. Thanks for clarifying the relationship between AES and Rijndael. I don't think Aes.Create was a standard when this code was written but none the less, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the bugs and it has to do with encoding and the response types and concatenation.

### Working solution

```js
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

  const passwordAndSalt = Buffer.from(password + salt, 'utf8');
  const inputEncoding = 'hex';

  const result = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(passwordAndSalt, inputEncoding), cipher.final()]);

  return result.toString('base64');
```

### Reasons

The result from the above was 50% longer because calling `.final('hex')` and appending to the result object was combining two hex objects. I assume that leads to issues when trying to display the result as `.toString('base64')`. Are you even able to `.toString('base64')` hex values?

If an output encoding isn't supplied, a Buffer is returned. So concatenating the buffers and base64 encoding them provides the correct hash!

### edit

This simplifies the returning of base64 with the recommendation from @Topaco.

```js
  const outputEncoding = 'base64';
  
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  
  const passwordAndSalt = Buffer.from(password + salt, 'utf8');

  let result = cipher.update(passwordAndSalt, null, outputEncoding);
  result += cipher.final(outputEncoding);

  return result;
```

Comment: `inputEncoding` is ignored since the input is a `Buffer`. Also, the crypto snippet from the question (the first one under *A few assumptions*) works as well if you specify `base64` as output encoding. The result is already a string (i.e. the `toString()` is not needed at all). See online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Ktu